# Fuction to return the first five columns in R

Tags: r

I wrote a function in R which is supposed to return the first five developers who made the most input:

```
developer.busy <- function(x){
  bus.dev <-  sort(table(test2$devf), decreasing = TRUE)
  return(bus.dev)
  }

 bus.dev(test2)

 ericb  shields     mdejong   cabbey   lord   elliott-oss   jikesadmin    coar 
 3224   1432         998       470      241   179            77           1
```

At the moment it just prints out all developers sorted in decreasing range. I just want the first 5 to be shown. How can I make this possible. Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Hi can you please give examples of yout input and desired output of data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we want the first five, either use index with `[` or with `head`.  Modified the function with three input, data object name, column name ('colnm') and number of elements to extract ('n')

```
developer.busy <- function(data, colnm, n){
     sort(table(data[[colnm]]), decreasing = TRUE)[seq_len(n)]
     # or another optioin is
     head(sort(table(data[[colnm]]), decreasing = TRUE), n)

 }

developer.busy(test2, "developerf", n = 5)
```

-using a reproducible example with `mtcars` dataset

```
data(mtcars)
developer.busy(mtcars, 'carb', 5)
#  2  4  1  3  6 
#10 10  7  3  1
```

Comment: Worked exactly like i wanted it. Thx I thougt about the seq_len.